# Javascript Countdown timer function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

I have developed a countdown timer function.

This function works fine. But the problem is it goes through the minus value too. So I want to stop the counting when its come to the `00:00:00`.
 How can I do this.please help me?

Javascript

```
function initCountdown() {

 if( seconds == 0 && minutes == 0 && hours == 0 ){
      clearInterval( interval ); }
 if (seconds < 10) {
      outputElement.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + "0" + seconds + " ";
 } else {
      outputElement.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " "; }} 
  function count(){
        time[2]--;
       if (time[2] == -1) {
          time[1]--;
          time[2] = 59
       }
    if (time[1] == -1) {
          time[0]--;
          time[1] = 59
         }
        print();
      }
   var outputElement = document.getElementById('demo');
   var time = document.getElementById("picker-dates1").value;
   time = time.split(':'); }
```

HTML

```
 <input type = "text" id = "picker-dates1"/>
 <P id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `clearInterval` function? Is it resetting the clock?

Comment: I don't see where you define seconds, minutes or hours from time[]

Comment: There's an extra bracket in `outputElement.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " "; }} `

Comment: Your script is not working (I tried on mozilla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `print();` with `if (time[0] >= 0) { print(); }`